# How to build a computing cloud for scientific computing?

Tags: maas, cloud

I have 5 computers with 4GB of RAM and 4 cores.

I would like to create a cloud where there is only one virtual machine that has 20 cores and 20GB of RAM or something close to this. I should be able to SSH and VNC.

I looked into MAAS, however I am not sure if it's the right product for me.

Can somebody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried it? What you think fits you best?

Answer (score 1):

What you want, is a cluster, not a "cloud." MaaS isn't what you're looking for, if you want to combine the computing resources of all the machines into a single resource. MaaS and other similar "cloud" tools allow you to manage many machines or VM instances, but does not provide clustering features inherent in the system.

You need to go look at the available clustering tools instead, to build a clustered system.